# Can not debug PyQt5 application with PyCharm

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5

So running my PyQt5 application is no problem with PyCharm. However, trying to debug it, I get this error message:

```sh
Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.7479.30)
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I managed to find some random Chinese post saying something about specifying `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` and so I set it to `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins` (I am using python 3.6). I now get a new error message saying:

```sh
Connected to pydev debugger (build 191.7479.30)
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50a01) with this library (version 0x50c02)

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I tried upgrading my PyQt5 package, but keep recieving the same error (but now the first version number is greater than the second). Do I need to upgrade the PyQt5 library? How would I do that?

Comment: According to the error message, you indicate that you are using the binaries for different versions (0x50a01-Qt 5.10.1 and 0x50c02-Qt.5.10.2), you may have installed 2 python, in one you installed PyQt5 5.10.1 and in the other PyQt5 5.10.2 and that causes the error.

Comment: How come it works fine when running then?

Comment: I do not use pycharm so they are only presumptions, I suppose that pydev has a configuration that eliminates certain things that avoid pointing to the QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH, and when you try to set it QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH you pass an incorrect path (that can be seen by the version)